# Is it possible to predict a batch of images with coremltools mlmodel?

Tags: coreml, coremltools, mlmodel

Is it possible to predict a batch in mlmodel? If yes, how?

I convert a keras model to mlmodel, as presented [in the documentation](https://coremltools.readme.io/docs/introductory-quickstart#convert-the-model):

```py
import coremltools as ct 
image_input = ct.ImageType(name='input', shape=(1, 224, 224, 3))
model = ct.convert(keras_model, inputs=[image_input])
```

Next, I load an image, resize it to (224, 224), transform it to PIL, and use it in prediction:

```py
img_resized = cv2.resize(img_read, (224, 224))
PIL_image = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(img_resized))
img_heatmap = self.model.predict({'input': PIL_image})
```

Is it possible to do it a **batch** of images instead of single image?

I've tried to define a batch of input type in the conversion:

```py
BATCH_SIZE = 8
image_input = ct.ImageType(name='input', shape=(BATCH_SIZE, 224, 224, 3))
model = ct.convert(keras_model, inputs=[image_input])
```

But it doesn't seem to change the model's input.

1. When I try to provide it with a **numpy array** of the `BATCH_SIZE` images (`(8, 224, 224, 3)`), I receive:

```
    return self.__proxy__.predict(data, useCPUOnly)
RuntimeError: value type not convertible
```

2. When I try to provide it with a **list of `BATCH_SIZE` PIL images** I receive:

```py
RuntimeError: {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Required input feature not passed to neural network.";
}
```

3. When I predict with a single image, the output is the same as the model with the `BATCH_SIZE=1`.

Is it possible to predict a batch? Thanks